# Send a command in open Minecraft from external Java Application

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am currently developing a bot, that by gathering data from the chat of a Minecraft server, it will tweet out who is actively controlling a certain capture point on a server. I have an account logged into the server (I am NOT an administrator or staff member though, so I cannot edit any server files or install plugins), and I am currently getting the chat data from the "latest.log" file, which works fine. The problem is, I need to execute a command from my player logged in, to see this info. Is there any possible way to do this, without me actively needing to be by my computer to type it?

NOTE: I am open to making a "Mod" for this, but it is less preferred, and any other workaround would suffice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [java.awt.Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) to send keyboard input to the active window.